# JavaScript how to split a string every n characters while ignoring ANSI codes

Tags: javascript, regex, terminal, ansi

How would you approach splitting a JavaScript string every `n` characters while ignoring the ansi codes? (so splitting every `n + length of ansi characters contained in that string`)

It is important to keep the ansi code in the final array.

I know using regex you'd write something like `/.{1,3}/`, but how would you ignore the ansi chars in the count?

Example:

Given `\033[34mHey \033[35myou\033[0m`, how would you split every 3 chars to get:

```
[
  '\033[34mHey',
  ' \033[35myo',
  'u\033[0m'
]
```

Comment: Try [`console.log(JSON.stringify("\033[34mHey \033[35myou\033[0m".match(/(?:(?:\033\[[0-9;]*m)*.?){1,3}/g).filter(Boolean)));`](http://jsfiddle.net/7znhzvdL/).

Comment: @stribizhev A detail: [if the last token's length is 3 and it ends with an ansi code, it sets the code in a new token](http://jsfiddle.net/s1yL8hhm/)

Comment: @Mariano: Here is [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7vbkvobb/) fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you need:

```js
s = "\033[34mHey \033[35myou\033[0mfd\033[1m";
chunks = s.match(/(?:(?:\033\[[0-9;]*m)*.?){1,3}/g);
var arr = [];
[].forEach.call(chunks, function(a) {
    if (!/^(?:\033\[[0-9;]*m)*$/.test(a)) {
  arr.push(a);
    }
});
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Note that octal codes can be used directly in the regex. We filter all the empty and ANSI-color code only elements in the `forEach` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can match ANSI color escapes as `\x1B\[[\d;]*m`, and only count all characters except escapes `[^\x1B]`

```
/(?:(?:\x1B\[[\d;]*m)*[^\x1B]){1,3}/g
```

Also, to include escapes in the end of string as part of the last token:

```
/(?:(?:\x1B\[[\d;]*m)*[^\x1B]){1,3}(?:(?:\x1B\[[\d;]*m)+$)?/g
```

**Code**

```js
subject = "\033[34mHey y\033[0mou\033[0m";
pattern = /(?:(?:\x1B\[[\d;]*m)*[^\x1B]){1,3}(?:(?:\x1B\[[\d;]*m)+$)?/g;

result = subject.match(pattern);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This doesn't account for ansi code inside the string. E.g. `\033[34mHey y\033[0mou\033[0m`

Comment: @SimonBoudrias it's a control character, so it's simply not printed. I edited the snippet to show them with `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: The example with JSON.stringify() replace `\033` with `\u001b`.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias That's the way it's shown. `\u001b` is exactly the same character as `\033`. result **contains the actual `\033`. It's a control character, so you can't print it**

Comment: It doesn't act the same way when you print it in a terminal.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I can explain it better. If there's something I'm missing, please create a fiddle to show input and expected result.